# How to use \dotfill if I do not have a command for it in LyX

Tags: lyx

Supposedly, newer versions of LyX have a command called \dotfill where one can obtain a string of dots such as in the following attachment. [image]

I am specifically looking for (lower) dots which are analogous to a horizontal fill. Further, I would prefer to be in Standard mode when doing this (as opposed to in Table of Contents).
When I enter math mode and insert \dotfill, nothing happens. How can I obtain these dots? If I have to add something to my LateX preamble, please share.

**EDIT**: When I enter \dotfill in LyX (in either inline or displayed mathmode) here is what I get [image]

Comment: There is the the `\@dottedtocline` command, but I am not sure where is usable at all outside of \tableofcontents etc.

Comment: `\dotfill` works in inline math. Does is have to be in displayed math mode?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that command does not work in my inline math. It also doesn't work in displayed math form. I have LyX version 2.0.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that command doesn't do anything in either inline or displayed math mode.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Which package contains `\dotfill` (Ok, I did not look so far ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No package needed, it is defined in the LaTeX kernel. The Substitute: Define 'does not work'.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer when I type \dotfill in math mode (inline or display), no dots appear.

Comment: You have to render the PDF, it doesn't appear in LyX. By the way, can you explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: . Thi]

You can write `\dotfill` in ERT (Evil Red Text) boxes with `Ctrl-L` in text mode (1) or math mode (2) or in blue boxes (`Ctrl-M`) in math inline mode (3). Anyway you obtain  `\dotfill` in the Lyx screen and the line of dots in the final PDF only. 
The `\dotfill` alone has no sense in display math mode with `Ctrl-L` (4) nor with `Ctrl-M` (5) as the the dotted line may shrink infinitely, so you must supply some space where it can be extended. One way to do is with a `\makebox` command (6). This is the LaTeX code produce made by the above Lyx screenshot:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\chi^{2}$\dotfill$\pi$
\item $\chi^2 \dotfill \pi$ 
\item $\chi^{2}\dotfill\pi$
\item \[\chi^2 \dotfill \pi\]
\item 
\[
\chi^{2}\dotfill\pi
\]

\item 
\[
\chi^{2}\makebox[10em]{\dotfill}\pi
\]
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

BTW, I think that for display math is better (simpler) use a chain of `\ldots`commands.